# Rewriting CSV file with particular rows omitted - Python 3

Tags: python, csv, url-rewriting

G'day,

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664965/updating-csv-file-add-remove-rows-with-python-3) question, and had some excellent responses from @abarnert. I'm trying to remove particular rows from a CSV file. I've learned that CSV files won't allow particular rows to be deleted, so I'm going to rewrite the CSV whilst omitting the particular rows, then rename the new file as the old.

As per the above question in the link, I have tools being taken and returned from a toolbox. The CSV file I'm trying to rewrite is an ongoing 'log' of the tools currently checked out from the toolbox. Therefore, when a tool is returned, I need that tool to be removed from the log CSV file.

Here's what I have so far:

```
absent_past = frozenset(tuple(row) for row in csv.reader(open('Absent_Past.csv', 'r')))
absent_current = frozenset(tuple(row) for row in csv.reader(open('Absent_Current.csv', 'r')))

tools_returned = [",".join(row) for row in absent_past - absent_current]

with open('Log.csv') as f:
    check = csv.reader(f)
    for row in check:
        if row[1] not in tools_returned:
            csv.writer(open('Log_Current.csv', 'a+')).writerow(row)

os.remove('Log.csv')
os.rename('Log_Current.csv', 'Log.csv')
```

As you can (hopefully) see from above, it will open the Log.csv file, and if a tool has been returned (ie. the tool is listed in a row in tools_returned), it will not rewrite that entry into the new file. When all the non-returned tools have been written to the new file, the old file is deleted, with the new file being renamed as Log.csv from Log_Current.csv.

It's worth mentioning that the tools which have been taken are appended to Log_Current.csv before it is renamed. This part of the code works nicely :)

I've been instructed to avoid using CSV for this system, which I agree with. I would like to explore CSV operation under Python as much as I can at this point however, as I know it will come in handy in the future. I will be looking to use the contextlib and shelve functions in the future.

Thanks!

EDIT: In the code above, I have if row[1]...which I'm hoping means that it will only check the value of the first column in the row? Basically, the row will consist of something like Hammer, James, Taken, 09:15:25, but I only want to search the Log.csv file for Hammer, as the tools_returned consists of only rows of tool names, ie. Hammer, Drill, Saw etc. Is the row[1] approach correct for this?

At the moment, the Log_Current.csv file is writing the Log.csv files regardless of whether the tool has been replaced or not. As such, I'm thinking that the if row[1] etc part of the code isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured I'd answer my own question, as I've now figured it out. The code posted above is correct, except for one minor error. When referring to the column number in a row, the first column is column 0, not column 1. As I was searching column '1' for the tool name, it was never going to work, as column '1 is actually the second column, which is the name of the user.

Changing that line to if row[0] etc rewrites a new file with the current list of tools that are checked out, and omits any tools that have been replaced, as desired!

Comment: StackOverflow should allow you to accept your own answer. So you should do that. (Unless you think it isn't worth having this here at all, in which case you should delete the question.)

Comment: Just tried deleting it, but I can't as there is an answer. I might just accept my answer then. Hopefully it will help someone else.